# How to Keep a Simple PHP application Inside a Laravel Application?

Tags: php, subdirectory, laravel-7

I have a Laravel Application hosted on example.com but I need to keep another simple PHP application (Named API) in that directory also such as example.com/api, but when I want to browse the example.com/api it gave me not found error. What I have to do to sort it out. [image]

Comment: Why do you need both? Consider building the functionality into your Laravel application, or moving one of them to a subdomain or something like that. Keeping both in the same folder will be difficult because of Laravel's routing engine.

Comment: @ADyson the PHP Application is very much big, and don't have enough time to upgrade to it Laravel, also I can't go for subdomain, Can you please suggest how may I do it with the settings right now. So right now I am bound to keep two things in one folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public directory is the document root of the web server. That is why you cannot access the api directory.

Place the api directory inside public. Be careful to protect any sensitive files.